# kubectl apply vs kubectl roll-update

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

If there an use case where kubectl apply should not be use to get a roll-update?

Despite the command original intent if we gave to kubectl apply a source file describing the resources of the cluster been updated over time, there any use case on which should not be use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The update strategy is specified in `.spec.strategy` in case of a Deployment and  `.spec.updateStrategy.type` for DaemonSets and StatefulSets

For Deployments `.spec.strategy.type` can be “Recreate” or “RollingUpdate”. “RollingUpdate” is the default value.

For DaemonSets and StatefulSets, `.spec.updateStrategy.type` can be "OnDelete" or "RollingUpdate". "OnDelete" is the default value.

`kubectl apply` will respect these strategies, so I see no reason why not using it.

`kubectl rolling-update` is used only for ReplicationControllers which were replaced by Deployments

Comment: I'll just add that declarative object management is the way to manage a production k8s cluster as its explained in the official docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/object-management-kubectl/object-management/

Comment: RollingUpdate is the default value for StatefulSets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets

Comment: this link has good details   https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81